# How to remove certain modules from article in joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla, module, article

I am new to *Joomla*, I have some module on my homepage.

Every time I open read more article on homepage, the slide show module still appear.

I have hiden the intro text but nothing change. If i uncheck the homepage, the module completely disappear on homepage and article.

Please teach me how to remove the module just on read more article not the homepage.
Sorry if my english is not good

Thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your articles are **uncategorized** or they they exist in a **category** that is not connected to a **menu item** (to get a unique menu id) you have to set module settings:

> Module -> Menu Assignment: On all pages except those selected

And select the pages that you don't want the module to appear.

**EDIT:**

If there is an option **to connect article categories to menu items** (even to a **hidden menu** that won't be displayed in the site) then the correct way is to set in the module:

> Module -> Menu Assignment -> Only on the pages selected

And select the pages that you want the module to appear.

Hope this helps

Comment: It works! Can i ask one more question?
How to link the article on hidden menu to home? So when the headline click it will appear.

Comment: Please add some extra details about your question, if you want the menu item to appear you could add it to your main menu instead of hidden menu.

Comment: I have made new menu item and connected to article. But this article can't be displayed unless I type the link. How to make that article headline can be displayed at home? Thanks.

Comment: You could add a module with type `Module Manager -> New -> Articles Category` or change the home page menu item to `Menu Item Type -> Articles -> Category Blog / Category List`.